# Displaying MYSQL data using PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a PHP beginner learner and I want to display all the results in a vertical way. For some reason, when there are multiple results, it just puts each result next to the other and not one over the other.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

This is my code

```
 include "conexiondb.php";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) { // Search is the "name" attribute in the HTML input. The ones used with the "$_POST"
    $busca = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['search'])) ;
    $criteria = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_POST['criteria'])) ;

    if ($busca!="") {
        $busqueda=$con->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE {$criteria} = '{$busca}' ");

        if ($busqueda === false) {
            die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }
    }

    echo  "<div id ='tablennvoltura'><table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Town</th>
<th>Zip</th>
<th>Cellphone</th>
<th>Birthday</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>id</th>

<th>Editar</th>
<th>Nueva orden</th>
<th>Ver Ordenes</th>
</tr>";

    while ($muestra=$busqueda->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<td>'.$muestra['name'].' </td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['address']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['town']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['zip']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['cellphone']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['birthday']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['email']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$muestra['id']. '</td>';
        echo "<td>"."<a href=\"memberdisplay.php?id=".$muestra['id']."\">See member</a>"." </td>";
        echo "<td>"."<a href=\"formproducto2.php?cedula=".$muestra['id']."\">Nueva Orden</a>"."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<a href=\"ordenes.php?cedula=".$muestra['id']."\">Ordenes</a>"."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
}

echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you place each variable into a table cell, but the cells are not encapsulated into a row (`<tr>... </tr>`).

```
while ($muestra=$busqueda->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    ...
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Actually, this question does not have too much to do with php, it is purely an html issue.